# make Facebook app tab visible only for admins of page

Tags: facebook, tabs, hide, admin, visible

Is there way to make app tab on facebook page be visible only for Admins of this page? App is intended for page admins, so other users shouldn't see this tab . Sand-box mode in this case doesn't suit of course.

Thanks!

Comment: No that is not possible

Comment: You can show different content though, based on whether the user viewing that page tab is an admin of the page or not. (That info can be found in the signed_request.)

Comment: @WizKid Thank you for your reply!